# Is JavaScript Object Model available outside of Sharepoint Hosted web pages?

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

Can I use JSOM or Rest JS on a webpage hosted outside of Sharepoint (somewhere like SalesForce) to access data in On-Premise SharePoint 2013? All the examples I have seen are for solutions hosted by SharePoint, like the Cross-domain library.

My goal is to GET and update data in SharePoint from outside SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript API can be used from another page... but you'll probably run into a [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) violation...

**Office 365**
Fortunately, with Office 365, there's now a way to workaround this policy by declaring an app in the Office 365 portal (the app declaration includes the domain name your JavaScript code is hosted at, e.g. your SalesForce or whatever third-party application URL); calls from this app will then be allowed by the mean of "CORS".
Official info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-cors-to-access-files-in-office-365) + a lot of [other articles](https://www.google.fr/search?q=office%20365%20cors%20sharepoint%20api).

**SharePoint on-prem**
For on-prem SharePoint server, you can enable CORS as well. This can be done at the server-level, by configuring IIS to allow API calls from another domain (i.e. the domain hosting your app, i.e. SalesForce). See these links to enable CORS:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367758/enable-cors-in-sharepoint-2013
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7
- https://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/

Once CORS is enabled on the SP server for your other domain, you can send REST requests to SharePoint from JavaScript.
If SP is configured for Windows authentication (NTLM or Kerberos), and if your browser is open with the credentials of the user (typically IE opened in a Windows domain session), SSO would take place and authentication should be OK.

Comment: I wish I could use Office 365, however my client does not have Office 365 or Azure, so we can not use either of them.

Comment: OK, it may be simpler in on-prem than with Office 365. I'll update my answer.